# Variable FOR LOOP in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to change to vary the interval size in a for loop?

Such as, the first loop looks at the first 3 values, and then the next loops looks at the next 13 values, and the next loop looks at the next 6 values... etc.

```
for (i in 1:1000, by = n)
```

Where `n` is not a constant number.

Comment: `for (i in seq(1, 1000, by = n))`

Comment: Yes simply write  `for (i in my_seq)` with `my_seq` being a vector predefined. But you question is not enough specific to help you building this vector

Comment: @zx8754 `n` is not constant. That's what I understood

Comment: @JRR where did I say it is?